# How do I pass my variable from public boolean to private void

Tags: java, android

I need to get the value of "markerPos" variable from the public boolean to private void in order to set it as a destination point of location. How can I get the value inside the private void?

Here's the codes

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
    int id = markers.get(marker.getId());

    //This is the value I need to pass on the other class
    LatLng markerPos = marker.getPosition();

    String id1 = marker.getTitle();

    //clear polyline for every marker click
    for(Polyline line : polylines)
    {
        line.remove();
    }
    polylines.clear();

    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + id1,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (id == 2) {
        // Add polylines to the map.
        // Polylines are useful to show a route or some other connection between points.
        polylines.add(this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .clickable(true)
                .add(
                        new LatLng(13.7926088,121.0025078),
                        new LatLng( 13.7924463,121.0025413),
                        new LatLng(13.792438, 121.002805),
                        new LatLng(13.792281, 121.002861),
                        new LatLng(13.792288, 121.003093))));
        getCurrentlocation();
    }
    return false;
}

private void getCurrentlocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if(location != null){
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

                            List<Address> addresses = null;
                            try {
                                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                                LatLng userloc = new LatLng((addresses.get(0).getLatitude()), (addresses.get(0).getLongitude()));

                                MarkerOptions userlocM = new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(userloc)
                                        .title("You")
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeBitmap("userloc",160,160)));

                                Marker mkr3 = mMap.addMarker(userlocM);
                                markers.put(mkr3.getId(), 3);
                                mOrigin = userloc;

                                //Here is where I want to put the markerPos value
                                mDestination =;
                                drawRoute();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        askPermission();
    }
}
```

I tried searching but I don't really get it. Is there a way to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different solutions. Maybe the simplest one is declaring `markerPos` as a class-level instance. So you may add something like

```
private LatLng MarkerPos;
```

to the class and then assign its value in the `onMarkerClick` method. Later in the `getCurrentlocation` method you can get its value.

At the end looks like:

```
public class ... {
// your class contents
private LatLng MarkerPos;

public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
// your method contents
MarkerPos = marker.getPosition();
// rest of your code
}

private void getCurrentlocation() {
// your method's code
mDestination = MarkerPos;
// rest of your code
}
}
```

Based on your work another solutions would be used. For example defining another class and using getter/setters.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass that variable as a parameter to the second method, if you change its signature like this.

```
private void getCurrentLocation(LatLng markerPos)
```

Then, when you call the method, you'll need to pass that value, like this.

```
getCurrentLocation(markerPos);
```

That way, the second method will be able to use `markerPos`, because it will have its own copy of the `markerPos` reference.

Comment: I got Cannot resolve symbol 'markerPos' error on the method under the private void getCurrentLocation(LatLng markerPos)

Comment: Then you've probably got other problems in your class that you'll need to sort out separately.  Start at the top and work downwards, resolving each compile error as you come to it.

Comment: This could be an alternative but the 2nd answer works the best for me